# Finding a basis for $\ker(T)$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, transformation

I have this question:

> Let $Z\in M_{2\times2}(\mathbb{R})$ be defined as
>
> $$Z = \left( \begin{align} 1 &&1\\1 &&1 \end{align} \right)$$
>
> and consider $T: M_{2\times2}(\mathbb{R}) \to M_{2\times2}(\mathbb{R})$ such that
>   $$T(X) = ZX$$
>
> Determine a basis for $\ker(T)$

Now I have transformation matrix with respect to the order basis as:

$$\left[ \begin{align} 1&&0&&1&&0\\0&&1&&0&&1\\1&&0&&1&&0\\0&&1&&0&&1 \end{align} \right]$$

Not sure if that is helpful for this, but I don't know how to work it out.

Is $\ker(T) = \emptyset$ or just the identity? I feel like there is no $\ker$.

Comment: Do you know how to find the basis for the nullspace of a matrix?

Comment: @AWertheim No I don't, should I just check wiki for nullspace basis?

Comment: Katie: that would be a good place to start, I think. :) This video may also be helpful: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qjkafy42CWg

Comment: the kernel is two-dimensional:
$$
\left( \begin{align} a &&b\\-a &&-b \end{align} \right)
$$

Comment: @yoyo If you post an answer, I'll be glad to remove mine; I felt it necessary to add a correct answer along with the (accepted) wrong one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The kernel of $T$ is
$$
\ker T=\{A\in M_{2\times2}(\mathbb{R}):T(A)=0\}
$$
that is $ZA=0$. You *can* find it using the representing matrix with respect to the basis $\{E_1,E_2,E_3,E_4\}$ where
$$
E_1=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}\quad
E_2=\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix}\quad
E_3=\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\1&0\end{bmatrix}\quad
E_4=\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}
$$
which is the matrix you wrote. Now row reduce it:
$$
\begin{bmatrix} 1&0&1&0\\0&1&0&1\\1&0&1&0\\0&1&0&1 \end{bmatrix}
\to
\begin{bmatrix} 1&0&1&0\\0&1&0&1\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0 \end{bmatrix}
$$
which means that the solutions of the homogeneous system are generated by the vectors
$$
\begin{bmatrix}-1\\0\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}
\quad\text{and}\quad
\begin{bmatrix}0\\-1\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}
$$
Taking into account the meaning of the representing matrix, we can say that
$$
\{-E_1+E_3,-E_2+E_4\}=
\left\{
\begin{bmatrix}-1&0\\1&0\end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix}0&-1\\0&1\end{bmatrix}
\right\}
$$
is a basis of the kernel of $T$.